# Will DateTime.UtcNow return different values within the same method?

Tags: c#, .net

Say that I have a long loop of simple math in between two calls to `DateTime.UtcNow` in a single method.

Does `DateTime.UtcNow` return two different values inside the same method if the code in between took more than the system's timer resolution of, say, 10 milliseconds?

By extension, is it possible, if the code runs right at the moment that the date turns over into a new day, that `DateTime.UtcNow.Date` will result in two different dates inside the same method?

Comment: Yes, yes and yes?

Comment: Yes, Time waits for no code. But if you were to put it into a variable then...

Comment: This is a very interesting question. The answers, as many have pointed out, is Yes. What prompts you to ask?

Comment: I was making multiple calls to DateTime.UtcNow in my code, but it was possible for bug to occur in my program if the date changed halfway through a method. I guess the chances of this occurring would be astronomically low, but I was curious and fixed it anyway by putting it in a variable like @Nkosi suggested. Sorry, I'm not a very knowledgeable programmer and probably have bigger things to worry about.

Comment: I would be very concerned if it *didn't* change value over 10 milliseconds

Comment: Time should stop when *my* function is called  :) ... Obviously reading externally provided value can change at any time - even two invocations next to each other can provide different values (just less frequently to make things more interesting to debug)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not carry out an experiment?

```
  DateTime t1 = DateTime.UtcNow;

  while (true) {
    DateTime t2 = DateTime.UtcNow;

    if (t2 != t1) {
      Console.Write($"{(t2 - t1).TotalMilliseconds}");

      break;
    }
  }
```

Outcome:

```
  1.0001
```

So, at my workstation `DateTime.UtcNow` has a resolution of **1** millisecond. And if the method takes **10** ms to complete, `DateTime.UtcNow` will *definetely* return the different values:

```
  DateTime t1 = DateTime.UtcNow;

  // 10 ms routine here
  DoSomething();

  // t1 != t2; t2 ~ t1.AddMilliseconds(10)
  DateTime t2 = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

There's minuscule probability that some PCs don't have *High Resilution Timer* [Stopwatch.IsHighResolution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution(v=vs.110).aspx); in this case the resolution drops to `3600 / 65536 * 1000 =` **55 ms** (System Timer resolution - `65536` ticks per hour) and there's a good chance that both `t1` and `t2` will be the *same*

Comment: There really no way "that both t1 and t2 will be the same" with code you shown - eventually UtcNow will return next values...

Answer (score 5):

`DateTime.UtcNow` is not evaluated nor its value is captured at method start.  It is evaluated at the time when execution reaches it, and every time the execution reaches it.  So yes, if function takes long enough, you will get to different values between two executions.

Comment: Side note: "if function takes long enough" - zero time is good enough - `DateTime.UtcNow != DateTime.UtcNow` occasionally will be true...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - well, yes and no at the same time.  It appears as if it is zero time, but it is actually not.  It's calling `.UtcNow` on left side, saving return value in one register, then doing the same and saving value in another register, then doing instruction to compare `!=`.  Call of left side and right side `.UtcNow` are not at the same time, and hence not zero-time.  And that's why value can change and thus the two not be equal.

Answer (score 2):

In one word: Yes.

If you want to have the same value you need to call this function before and store the value on a variable, then use this variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will return different values.

Following is from [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets a DateTime object that is set to the current date and time on this computer, expressed as the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Running your code takes time and time is what it returns. So yes, it will change even in same function.